# error in activing set-device-owner using adb

Tags: android, adb, pinning, dmp

i want to set device owner and active on my application using adb and dpm . i want to use `startlocktask().` for creating kiosk application.
 but when i run this line in my commandline:

```
./adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.pakban.mobile.pinningtest/.AdminReceiver
```

i recived an error like this :

```
Error: Bad admin: ComponentInfo{com.pakban.mobile.pinningtest/com.pakban.mobile.pinningtest.AdminReceiver}
```

thanks for your answers

Comment: May be this could be useful: http://florent-dupont.blogspot.fr/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html

Comment: thanks, but in your link, there is no post or answer about this error. final post is mine in this link :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my case, i used tutorial on net like this link

http://florent-dupont.blogspot.fr/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html

at this time, non of example and tutorial not mentioned how to create device_admin xml file(or i couldn't find it). so you need create a folder under res with "xml" name. and then, you must create a xml file with "device_admin" name. in this xml file just add this tag:

```
<device-admin>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: can we execute "dpm set-device-owner..." command programmatically. I tried but not succeed..

Answer (score 1):

Just check your "AndroidManifest.xml" once and make sure you have mentioned receiver's attributes value properly.